# variables_to_restore has NotFoundError

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have a variable v and want to apply moving average to it. I applied the following steps to save it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
v=tf.Variable(0,dtype=tf.float32,name='v')
ema=tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(0.99)
maintain_averages_op=ema.apply(tf.global_variables())
init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
saver=tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    sess.run(tf.assign(v,10))
    sess.run(maintain_averages_op)
    saver.save(sess, 'C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Neural_Network.model.ckpt')
    sess.run([v, ema.average(v)])
```

After saving this session, I want to restore it and assign `'v/ExponentialMovingAverage'` to `v` directly using `variables_to_restore`
This is the code:

```
v=tf.Variable(0,dtype=tf.float32,name='v')
ema=tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(0.99)
print(ema.variables_to_restore())
saver=tf.train.Saver(ema.variables_to_restore())
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess,'C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Neural_Network.model.ckpt')
    sess.run(v)
```

However, there is NotFoundError:

```
NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key v/ExponentialMovingAverage/ExponentialMovingAverage_1 not found in checkpoint
```

I'm a bit confused with the output of `print(ema.variables_to_restore())`:

```
{'v/ExponentialMovingAverage/ExponentialMovingAverage_1': <tf.Variable 'v/ExponentialMovingAverage:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>, 'v_1/ExponentialMovingAverage_1': <tf.Variable 'v_1:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>, 'v_3/ExponentialMovingAverage': <tf.Variable 'v_3:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>, 'v/ExponentialMovingAverage_2': <tf.Variable 'v:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>, 'v_2/ExponentialMovingAverage_1': <tf.Variable 'v_2:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>, 'v/ExponentialMovingAverage_1': <tf.Variable 'v/ExponentialMovingAverage_1:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>, 'v_1/ExponentialMovingAverage': <tf.Variable 'v_1/ExponentialMovingAverage:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>, 'v/ExponentialMovingAverage/ExponentialMovingAverage': <tf.Variable 'v/ExponentialMovingAverage/ExponentialMovingAverage:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>, 'v_2/ExponentialMovingAverage': <tf.Variable 'v_2/ExponentialMovingAverage:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>}
```

Why there are so many variables `v_1, v_2` etc.? How can I correct the NotFoundError and compute the moving average of v using `variables_to_restore`?

Answer (score 0):

If tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(0.99) is called twice in the same program, then ExponentialMovingAverage_1 will be created.